# React - passing this.state as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried researching everywhere I can but I'm stuck on why my code wont work.

I'm trying to update this.state with new data and then pass this to the react-bootstrap-table tool (http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example)

I'm trying to pass this.state as a prop in the "data" prop, however when I try this I get the following error:

```
react-bootstrap-table.min.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: n.props.data.slice is not a function
```

I've googled the error and got to this document (https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/issues/605) which talked about using a componentWillReceiveProps but I've had no luck with this.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Steve

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {

};
this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
}

//method to fetch data from url  
getData(url){

fetch(url)
  .then(function(resp){
    return resp.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    //do something with the data

  this.setState(data)

  }) 
} //end of getData function

componentDidMount(){
//Details location of our data
var url = "https://fcctop100.herokuapp.com/api/fccusers/top/recent";

//fetches data from url

this.getData(url);   
} //end of componentDidMount


render(){

return (
<BootstrapTable data={this.state} striped hover>
  <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='username'>Username</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField='recent'>Recent Score</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField='alltime'>All Time Score</TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>

);
}


} //end of App class
ReactDOM.render(<App data = {this.state}/>,
            document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `render` method to something like below. You need to send `data` that is fetched in `getData` and not the whole state object to the `BootstrapTable`. Moreover, the data you get back in the `.then` should match BootstrapTable's expectation of data.

Also remember that `this.state.data` will not be populated when the component first renders. Only after `fetchUrl` fulfils `this.state.data` will be populated.

```
render(){

  return (
    <BootstrapTable data={this.state.data || []} striped hover>
      <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='username'>Username</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='recent'>Recent Score</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='alltime'>All Time Score</TableHeaderColumn>
    </BootstrapTable>

  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nandu, was driving me mad why I couldn't solve it!